# Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am writing a powershell code with an SQL query to get information from one of our Databases and then put that information into a variable for further use.
My entire code works, and does exactly what i want it to do.

But somewhere in this snippet of the code two errors are produced that I can't figure out why happen if the script is actually doing what it's supposed to do.

```
$Server = "######"
$Database = "######"
$UserSqlQuery = "SELECT [UdstyrsId]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Serienr]
      ,[Udlevdato]
      ,[Repnr]
      ,[Notat]
  FROM [IT-Support].[dbo].[Udstyrsoplysninger] where aflevdato is null and repnr = $repnr"

    function ExecuteSqlQuery($Server, $Database, $UserSQLQuery) 
    {
        $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
        $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';integrated security=true;"
        $Connection.Open()
        $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
        $Command.Connection = $Connection
        $Command.CommandText = $UserSQLQuery
        $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader();
        $Datatable.Load($Reader);
        $Connection.Close()

        return $Datatable
    }    
        $ResultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $ResultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery
```

## Error code:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax        near '='."
At C:\Users\adm-#######\Desktop\UserResignation.ps1:70 char:13
+             $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader();
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataReader"
At C:\Users\adm-#######\Desktop\UserResignation.ps1:71 char:13
+             $Datatable.Load($Reader);
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

Line 70 and 71 is these lines in the script:

```
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader();
$Datatable.Load($Reader);
```

Comment: Did you set `$repnr` ? Seems like your `$UserSqlQuery` has syntax error because your where condition missing value.

Comment: @KirillPashkov Hi, yes the $repnr is set earlier in the script through a $repnr = (Get-ADuser -identity JohnDoe -properties * | select Office).Office

Comment: what is the value in the `$Reader` in the `$Datatable.Load($Reader)`?  Btw. you can omit the `;` at the end with powershell.

Comment: @SimonBøgelund, seems like `$repnr` is null or empty.

Comment: That strikes me as odd, cause just a few lines above the code I posted I save repnr in $RepNr = (Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties * | Select-Object Office).office. So it should be populated.

Comment: Though @KirillPashkov already spotted the error, it's worth mentioning `Set-StrictMode`. It will catch non-set variables and other common errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to declare `$repnr` for query's `where` condition and because of that you get syntax error `where aflevdato is null and repnr =` .

```
$repnr = 123
$UserSqlQuery = "SELECT [UdstyrsId]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Serienr]
      ,[Udlevdato]
      ,[Repnr]
      ,[Notat]
  FROM [IT-Support].[dbo].[Udstyrsoplysninger] where aflevdato is null and repnr = $repnr"
```

Comment: Good spotting Kirill!

Comment: This turned out to be the reason actually. 
Earlier on in my script I have another variable:
$CN = Get-ADUser -Properties accountexpirationdate -Filter { (Enabled -EQ $True -and AccountExpirationDate -GE 0) } | Where-Object { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Eksterne*') } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

This returns all the users in our AD with an expiration date. They are then put through a foreach loop, where the $repnr variable is set.

Comment: The $repnr is based on the value in the Office Property.
The first line caught a user that I thought I had exempted and that specific users Office property wasn't populated resulting in the $repnr to be null in the SQL query later on in the script.